# Replace text in a url using PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

So basically I got links like these

```
https://dog.example.com/randomgenerated45443444444444
https://turtle.example.com/randomgenerated45443
https://mice.example.com/randomgenerated452
https://monkey.example.com/randomgenerated43232323
https://leopard.example.com/randomgenerated22222222222222222
```

I was wondering if it was possible to detect the words between `https://` and `.example.com/` which would be the random animal name. And replace it with "thumbnail". The amount of letters in the animal names and randomgenerated ones always vary in amount of letters in them

Comment: yes. it is possible. but: have you even *tried* anything yet?

Comment: It's possible. You basically need to separate the TLD from the rest. I recommend [TLDExtract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract). As it's a heck of a lot more accurate that `parse_url()` or some ad-hoc regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead to get to the data you want:

```
$string = 'https://leopard.example.com/randomgenerated22222222222222222';
$pattern = '/(?=.*\/\/)(.*?)(?=\.)/';
$replacement = 'thumbnail';
$foo = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

$protocol = 'https://';
echo $protocol . $foo;
```

returns

> https://thumbnail.example.com/randomgenerated22222222222222222

Explanation of the regex:

**Positive Lookahead** (`?=.*\/\/`)
Assert that the Regex below matches
   `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)
   `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   `\/` matches the character `/` literally (case sensitive)
   `\/` matches the character `/` literally (case sensitive)
**1st Capturing Group** (.*?)
   `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)
   `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
**Positive Lookahead** (`?=\.`)
Assert that the Regex below matches
   `\.` matches the character . literally (case sensitive)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that `https://` and `example.com` never change, then this is the simplest regex you can use for the purpose:

`https://(.+)\.example\.com`

Anything in the `(.+)` will be the words you are attempting to extract.

---

Edit on 2016.10.27:

While **the `/` character has no special meaning in Regular Expressions**, it will likely need to be escaped (`\/`) if you are *also* using it as your expression delimiter. So the above will look like:

`https:\/\/(.+)\.example\.com`

Comment: You should test your regex, it does not work at all. It fails because you have not properly escaped the slashes at the beginning. https://regex101.com/ is a good place to test. [Here is an example using your regex](https://regex101.com/r/9gzOGQ/1)

Comment: @JayBlanchard If you go and look at the official PHP docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php you will read that `/` is _not_ by definition a special RegExp character. The reason it may need escaping is when it is used as a delimiter in a RegExp literal. My example was the pure RegExp pattern, for ease of reading.